# FFMPEG mp4 videos not suddenly stops playing on Browsers

Tags: laravel, video, ffmpeg, html5-video, ffmpeg-php

I have been struggling with this issue in regards to playing my **converted mp4 videos** using **FFMPEG** into an **html 5 video player**, I basically just use a single video player and just replace the source when the video ends.

What happens is that a **MediaError** occurs randomly with different videos saying:

`PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: Failed to send audio packet for decoding`

or

`PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: audio decode error`

Videos have no issues on **Safari**, **Internet Explorer**, and **Firefox**. But this error shows up randomly on **Opera** and **Google Chrome**.

I am using Laravel [Laravel FFMpeg][1] to convert the videos, please see my **conversion code** below:

```
$bitrateFormat = (new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264'))->setKiloBitrate(1500);

$converted_video = FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos')
    ->open($this->video_id)
    ->addFilter(['-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p'], ['-movflags', '+faststart'])
    ->export()
    ->inFormat($bitrateFormat)
    ->toDisk('do_spaces_video')
    ->save($this->video_id);
```

Any help would be appreciated guys, thanks in advance!

**EDIT - Added Media Internals Error**

```
00:04:02.892    for_suspended_start false
00:04:02.892    pipeline_buffering_state    BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:04:33.919    error   Failed to send audio packet for decoding: timestamp=272341333 duration=21333 size=346 side_data_size=0 is_key_frame=1 encrypted=0 discard_padding (us)=(0, 0)
00:04:33.919    error   audio decode error
00:04:33.943    error   audio error during playing, status: PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE
00:04:33.943    pipeline_error  PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE
00:04:33.944    pipeline_state  kStopping
00:04:33.945    pipeline_state  kStopped
00:04:33.950    event   PAUSE
```

Comment: What does media internals say?

Comment: hey @szatmary, I have added the media internals screenshot on the question, here is the img https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhsYM.png. :D

Comment: Please don't add pictures of text. Its creates extra work for the people trying to help you, and makes the question not searchable, meaning it can't help others with the same problem.

Comment: hey @szatmary, noted will add the internals by text.

Comment: Hi @szatmary I was able to add the media internals text, thanks again for helping me on this. :)